# What is the greatest value...

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the first three terms of a geometric progression is 21, and the sum of their squares is 1281. What is the greatest value can be the sum of the cubes?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,ar,ar^2$ be the three terms

So, $a+ar+ar^2=21$

So, $(a)^2+(ar)^2+(ar^2)^2=1281\implies a(r^2+r+1)a(r^2-r+1)=1281$

On division, $a-ar+ar^2=\frac{1281}{21}=61$

So, $ar=-20,a+ar^2=41$

$a^3+(ar)^3+(ar^2)^3=a^3+(ar^2)^3+(-20)^3$
$=(a+ar^2)^3-3a\cdot ar^2(a+ar^2)+(-20)^3$
$=(41)^3-3(-20)^2(41)+(-20)^3$

Comment: @Henry, would you please verify the edited answer?

Comment: That is the answer I get

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- You have two distinct equalities and two unknowns so there are a finite number of solutions satisfying the equalities.  So start by solving the equalities
- If $S_1$ is the sum of the three terms and $S_2$ is the sum of their squares you could start by looking at $\dfrac{S_1^2-S_2}{2S_1}$ to see if this gives you anything useful
- $21^2 = 441 \lt 1281$, so not all the terms in the geometric progression can be positive

Comment: The middle term is $\frac{21^2-1281}{2\times 21}=-20$, so the initial term is a solution to $a^2-41a+400=0$ so is $16$ or $25$, in which case the final term is then $25$ or $16$, giving a single possible value for the sum of the cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Call the terms $\dfrac{b}{r}$, $b$, and $br$.  Square the sum. We get 
$$\frac{b^2}{r^2}+b^2+b^2r^2 +2b\left(\frac{b}{r}+b+br\right).$$
Thus $441= 1281+2b(21)$. It follows that $b=-20$. The rest is routine.

If we want to do the rest prettily, use
$$\frac{1}{r^3}+r^3=\left(\frac{1}{r}+r\right)^3-3\left(\frac{1}{r^2}+r^2\right).$$